# Run bash_aliases on start

Tags: linux, debian, bashrc, crunchbang, bash-alias

I have a separate file `.bash_aliases` , in the same directory as `.bashrc`, that I wish to be ran on start, I've added the lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

to my `.bashrc` but none of the commands in the `.bash_aliases` file are working.

My .bash_alises file

```
ll='ls -l'
sublime='/home/colin/bin/SublimeText2/sublime_text'
```

Comment: Try using absolute addresses, not relative ones.

Comment: Made no difference.

Comment: Did you check if the `.bashrc` itself gets executed? You can insert for example this testing code: `{ date --rfc-3339=seconds ; ps ; } >/tmp/bashrc$$`.

Comment: If I uncomment an `ll` command out and run `source ~/.bashrc` that command then works so I assume it is getting executed.

Comment: What commands *are* inside your `~/.bash_aliases` file?

Comment: `sublime='/home/colin/bin/SublimeText2/sublime_text'` the command in quotes works fine if I type it directly into a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your .bash_aliases file should look like.

> **alias** ll='ls -l'
>   **alias** sublime='/home/colin/bin/SublimeText2/sublime_text'

(note the extra alias at the start of the command).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

with absolute paths of course

Comment: I've tried `if [ -f /home/colin/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source /home/colin/.bash_aliases
fi` but the command in the file is still not found.

Comment: as grawity asked, can you paste at least the beginnig of your bash_aliases?

Comment: See edit for whole file